# angularjs ng-show: show menu after successful login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to show the navigation bar once the user logs in successfully. but the navigation-bar is still hidden even after the user logs in.
here is a part of the index.html

```
    <header id="Header1" data-ng-controller="navigationController">
        <!-- Navigation bar -->


        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="nav1" ng-hide="isConnected">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">


                <ul id="Ul1" class="nav navbar-nav" style="color: white; font-weight: bolder; font-family: Arial; border-radius: 5px;">

                    <!-- <li class="nav navbar-brand" id="Li1" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <img src="favicon.ico" height="20" width="20" />
                </li>-->


                    <li id="Li2" data-ng-class="{'active':isActive('/home')}">
                        <a data-original-title="Home page." class="disable-click" href="#/home">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li data-ng-class="{'active':isActive('/demo')}">
                        <a data-original-title="Demonstration page." class="disable-click" href="#/demo">Demonstration</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div> 
        </nav>
    </header>
```

the controller navigationController.js is

```
'use strict';
 app.controller('navigationController',
function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, AuthenticationService) {
    debugger;
    $scope.isActive = function (path) {
        return $location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path;
    };

        $scope.isConnected = !($rootScope.globals.currentUser);

    console.log($scope.isConnected);
});
```

i store the current user in this service

```
 service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
        var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
                authdata: authdata
            }
        };

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; 
        $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
    };
```

the binding is not working after the login, except when i refresh the menu is shown (when the cookie has became full). any solution please

Comment: It's because your controller run first and doesn't get updated. You could fire an event when you set the cookie and the user is authenticated which the controller could listen to and update `isConnected `. You can use `$scope.$on` and `$rootScope.$broadcast` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your isConnected property is only evaluated once when the controller is instantiated. When the user logs in there is nothing to re-evaluate isConnected

You could set up a watch like this to have it re-evaluate:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('navigationController',
function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, AuthenticationService) {
    debugger;
    $scope.isActive = function (path) {
        return $location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path;
    };

    $rootScope.$watch('globals', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.isConnected = !($rootScope.globals.currentUser);
    }, true);
});
```

note it might be possible you can add the watch directly to $scope instead of $rootScope as the globals property should be inherited prototypically, though I haven't tested this to verify

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'use strict';
 app.controller('navigationController',
function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, AuthenticationService) {
    ...

    $scope.isConnected = function() {
        return !($rootScope.globals.currentUser);
    };
});
```

And do not change ng-hide value to `ng-hide="isConnected()"`, keep it as `ng-hide="isConnected"`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="nav1" ng-hide="isConnected">
    ...
```